# Why is some code still highlight when commented?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

I was reading a piece of code and noticed that some variables were still highlighted after comments. But when I remove a '*', the code is no longer highlighted. Why is that? What's the difference between the two.Btw,my editor is Visual Studio Code.

[image: Source code comment block beginning with /**]

when i delete a '*' :

[image: Source code comment block beginning with /*]

Comment: Because you probably have a plugin to display doc-tags. `/**` is one common start for doc-tags

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because because it is not a programming question.

Comment: @0___________ It is a question about programming tool, which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @0___________ this is a programming question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between /\* and /\*\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357887/difference-between-and)

Comment: Unfortunately this cannot be answered. Despite its name, Visual Studio Code is not a C-C++ IDE but is just a text editor. It relies on *plugins* to highlight code according to a language and launch tools. That means that without knowing the detailed configuration of your project (used plugins and their configuration), nobody can knows what *thing* decided to highlight something. That being said, the underlying reason was already pointed out by @TedLyngmo's comment.

Comment: @PtitXav Excellent link! It explains it well although it's for java. Would close the question as a duplicate but I already voted to close it for another reason so I can't. :-)